# Power BI custom visual, creating multiple objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, powerbi

I am having troubles while creating multiple objects (amount of objects is based on input data). Have already tried creating an array, but I had to know many objects I will need to create before getting data. Anyone knows how to do that?

My code -

```
module powerbi.extensibility.visual {
    export class Visual implements IVisual {
        private lines: d3.Selection<SVGElement>[];
        private svg: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
        private container: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;

        constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
            this.svg = d3.select(options.element)
                .classed("svg",true)

            this.container = this.svg.append("g")
                .classed("container", true)

            var a = []
            for(var i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
                a[i] = this.container.append("line")
                    .classed("line_"+String(i), true)
            }

            this.lines = a;
        }

        public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

a[i] = this.svg.container.append("line")